# Using a blinding factor for RSA in pycrypto

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

In python, I am trying to blind and unblind a message. When I unblind the message, I don't get the original message. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong. The following is my code:

```
s = 'Hello'
loadedPublic = get_publickey()
loadedPrivate = get_privatekey()

pub = loadedPublic.blind(s,23L)
pub2 = loadedPublic.unblind(pub,23L)
return HttpResponse(pub2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blinding is a sort of encryption with a random element. It is usually used for [Blind Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) which would look like this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from random import SystemRandom

# Signing authority (SA) key
priv = RSA.generate(3072)
pub = priv.publickey()

## Protocol: Blind signature ##

# must be guaranteed to be chosen uniformly at random
r = SystemRandom().randrange(pub.n >> 10, pub.n)
msg = "my message" * 50 # large message (larger than the modulus)

# hash message so that messages of arbitrary length can be signed
hash = SHA256.new()
hash.update(msg)
msgDigest = hash.digest()

# user computes
msg_blinded = pub.blind(msgDigest, r)

# SA computes
msg_blinded_signature = priv.sign(msg_blinded, 0)

# user computes
msg_signature = pub.unblind(msg_blinded_signature[0], r)

# Someone verifies
hash = SHA256.new()
hash.update(msg)
msgDigest = hash.digest()
print("Message is authentic: " + str(pub.verify(msgDigest, (msg_signature,))))
```

[This](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/7acba5f3a6ff10f1424c309d0d34d2b713233019/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py#L41-L47) is how it is implemented, so you cannot directly unblind the message, because you don't have `d`, so the blinded element must be signed first. In order for the blind signature to be secure, you need to randomly generate the blinding factor `r` in the range of the signing modulus.